# Error on Start Database Kitematic Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, postgis, kitematic

I've made a database and a "connection" with Kartoza Postgis, but I can't start it, here's the log:

```
 Session terminated, terminating shell...2019-01-01 20:06:31.524 UTC [222] LOG:  worker process: logical replication launcher (PID 231) exited with exit code 1
2019-01-01 20:06:31.524 UTC [222] LOG:  received smart shutdown request
Add rule to pg_hba: replication user
Setup master database
Use modified postgresql.conf for greater speed (spatial and replication)
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
2019-01-01 20:18:30.074 UTC [25] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2019-01-01 20:18:30.243 UTC [25] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2019-01-01 20:18:30.628 UTC [42] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2019-01-01 20:02:40 UTC
2019-01-01 20:18:30.697 UTC [50] postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
psql: FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2019-01-01 20:18:31.512 UTC [42] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2019-01-01 20:18:31.594 UTC [42] LOG:  redo starts at 0/1ED67D8
2019-01-01 20:18:31.747 UTC [42] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/1F0D290: wanted 24, got 0
2019-01-01 20:18:31.748 UTC [42] LOG:  redo done at 0/1F0D258
2019-01-01 20:18:31.749 UTC [42] LOG:  last completed transaction was at log time 2019-01-01 20:03:13.699387+00
2019-01-01 20:18:31.814 UTC [63] postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
psql: FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2019-01-01 20:18:33.013 UTC [76] postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
psql: FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2019-01-01 20:18:33.381 UTC [25] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

https://pastebin.com/zuxYthqC

I use Kitematic and when i try to start the database, the same goes "starting" followed by "stopped" with the log above.

Here is an image from mi Kitematic:
[Kitematic Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cCTO.png)